# Apache POI : Copy data to Particular sheet at particular cell with Merged Columns in Source Sheet

Tags: apache-poi

### Problem

How to add some part of data from source excel sheet to the destination excel sheet using Apache POI(XSSF Format)?Excel sheet contains merged columns.

### Requirement:

1. Requirement is not only to copy the row but also to put the data into desired Excel cell(desired column) of the destination sheet.

### Note

-Copying row to desired row location in destination excel sheet is achievable. Problem is to first merge the cell as per source sheet in destination sheet and then put data into desired merged excel cell.
- Merged Columns could vary in a row.

Here is the source code, half referred and half written.

```
public static void copyNodeFrmtSrcToDest(XSSFSheet srcSheet, XSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRowStart,XSSFRow srcRowEnd
        ,XSSFRow destRowStart, int destCellStart, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap){

    /*Check if there is only one row to be pasted*/
    int noOfRows = srcRowEnd.getRowNum() - srcRowStart.getRowNum();
    /*Check if there is only one row to be pasted*/
    if(noOfRows == 0)
    {
        /*Copy a single row*/
        copyRow(srcSheet,destSheet,srcRowStart,destRowStart,destCellStart,styleMap);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0;i <= noOfRows ;i++)//For every row
    {
        /*Get rows from source sheet and increment it*/
        XSSFRow srcIntermediateRow =  srcSheet.getRow(srcRowStart.getRowNum() + i);
        if(destRowStart == null)
        {
            try {
                throw new RowNotFoundError("Row has not been found in the sheet.Kindly create a row.");
            } catch (RowNotFoundError e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        if(i!=0)//Assuming destRowStart has been created by user of the API
        {
            /*Create a new row*/
            destRowStart = destSheet.createRow(destRowStart.getRowNum()+1);
        }
        copyRow(srcSheet,destSheet,srcIntermediateRow,destRowStart,destCellStart,styleMap);
    }
}

public static void copyRow(XSSFSheet srcSheet, XSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRow, XSSFRow destRow, int destCellStart,
        Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {
    int count = 1;
    Set<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = new HashSet<CellRangeAddress>();
    CellRangeAddress previousMergedRegion =null;
    destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
    for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        int mergedDiff;
        XSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
        XSSFCell newCell;
        if(j == srcRow.getFirstCellNum()){
        newCell = destRow.getCell(destCellStart);}
        else
        {
            newCell = destRow.getCell(destCellStart + count);

        }
        if (oldCell != null) {
            if (newCell == null) {
                if(j == srcRow.getFirstCellNum()){
                newCell = destRow.createCell(destCellStart);//Keeping the new cell as the first one.
                copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
                }
                else{
                    newCell = destRow.createCell(destCellStart + count);
                    count = count + 1;
                    copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);}
            }

            CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(),oldCell.getColumnIndex());
            if(previousMergedRegion != null && mergedRegion != null)
            {

                mergedDiff = mergedRegion.getLastColumn() - mergedRegion.getFirstColumn();
                if(!previousMergedRegion.equals(mergedRegion))
                {
                    destCellStart = destCellStart + mergedDiff + 1;
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
            if (mergedRegion != null) {
                previousMergedRegion = mergedRegion.copy();
                mergedDiff = mergedRegion.getLastColumn() - mergedRegion.getFirstColumn();
                CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(destRow.getRowNum(),destRow.getRowNum()
                        ,destCellStart,destCellStart + mergedDiff);

                if (isNewMergedRegion(newMergedRegion, mergedRegions))
                {
                    mergedRegions.add(newMergedRegion);
                    destSheet.addMergedRegion(newMergedRegion);
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

public static void copyCell(XSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {
    if(styleMap != null) {
        if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
        } else{
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
            XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
            if(newCellStyle == null){
                newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
            }
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
        }
    }
    switch(oldCell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
        case STRING:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case NUMERIC:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case BLANK:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case BOOLEAN:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case ERROR:
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;
        case FORMULA:
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, int cellNum) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
        CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {
            return merged;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion, Set<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions)
{
    if(mergedRegions.isEmpty())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);
}
```

}

It is working fine for some testcases but not for all.

Comment: @Shagun First show your efforts what you have tried... then we will try to help you where need update/improvement.

Comment: Kindly Check. I have provided the source code.

Comment: Offer, checking this code for all possible test cases: 10.000,00 EUR. In serious: What are the test cases which fails? In what do they differ from the test cases which are working fine?